# XNA 4.0 game doesn't do anything when ran on another PC

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

This issue is getting real tiresome and I've been spending atleast 2 days looking around for an answer. Basically, I want to publish a game, and I've hired a friend of mine to test it out before I officially release it. Whenever he runs it, reports as "nothing happends".

These conditions are met:

- He has installed the .NET Framework 4.0 and the XNA Redistributable 4.0 (he most likely also has installed other .NET Frameworks and XNA Frameworks as well, because nothing worked).
- The game is compiled onto a Release build.
- GamerService referenced is removed.

A possible issue could be that he's using Win8, but as my searching experience goes, XNA DEVELOPMENT is only restricted on Windows 8, right?

So, what's going on? I'm clueless.. I even put a `MessageBox.Show();` after the execution of my game in my `Program.cs` file via `try`/`catch`, and no results.

Are there any extreme conditions in my code that I need to meet?
Any site describing 100% of all requirements to run an XNA game and the most proper way to build it?

Any issues when using non-distributable "developer tools" in XNA coding? If so, what includes in these "developer tools", and what do I need to modify? (I noticed that on another thread).

An answer to this issue would more than make my day...

Ah, and also, I tried running it on a virtual machine ( Windows 7 ) but then it spat out a messagebox saying `Index outside the bounds of the array` on a perfectly valid code execution, and various other random errors such as missing files when they clearly are there.

Thank you greatly!

Comment: what do you mean by win8? if you mean winRT then you're basically out of luck. But XNA works fine in the desktop environment of windows 8/8.1 pro.

Comment: Yikes. Yes, sorry, I meant Windows 8. I would like to distribute the game via the Release build (copying the folder, and running the main .exe). But I'm a bit confused, @micky-duncan just mentioned XNA didn't make a good Windows 8 app _Officially, desktop games using unmodified Microsoft XNA 4/is not supported on Windows 8 in any form_? I also read I had to give MonoGame a shot for XNA to run on Windows 8

Comment: What you're describing sounds like XNA isn't installed correctly. Make sure the correct version of .NET is installed and that XNA is installed *after* that. Try looking in the Windows event viewer for the crash message from your game.

Comment: This also sounds like a file path issue.  If you use absolute path for your files, your binary will not work on other people's computers.

Comment: Check your windows error logs

Answer (score 1):

In summary I think your app wont run on Windows 8, let me explain:

### Windows 8

> A possible issue could be that he's using Win8, but as my searching experience goes, XNA DEVELOPMENT is only restricted on Windows 8, right?

Officially, desktop games using unmodified Microsoft XNA 4/is not supported on Windows 8 in *any* form:

> *Microsoft officials have said the XNA tools/**runtime environment** used primarily by game developers **isn't supported on Windows 8**.* [- Read more...](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsofts-windows-phone-8-finally-gets-a-real-windows-core/12975)

### Redistributables

> Any issues when using non-distributable "developer tools" in XNA coding?

That depends on whether they are required at runtime on the target machine.  That might sound like an oxymoron but in Windows c/c++, I can have an app that depends on Microsoft DLLs but we are not allowed to deploy the DLLs, one must depend on it being present in the OS; service pack or some other form.  Is there something you are missing?

### Windows 7

> Ah, and also, I tried running it on a virtual machine ( Windows 7 ) but then it spat out a messagebox saying **Index outside the bounds of the array** on a perfectly valid code execution

This is more interesting and I suspect is one of the more testable aspects of your application (also that it is not Windows 8).   I suggest you setup a remote-debug session to your Win7 VM or if that is not possible, use Debug.WriteLine() or equivalent displaying critical state contents.